# NSNumberFormatter: string to Double

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am trying to take a user input from a text field and format it into a double value for core data. Currently my code looks like:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber *weightDouble = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"weight.text"];
```

However, if I print weightDouble I get 0, if I print out the text from the UI input I get the correct number. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here? I get no errors on the build and it operates and saves fine (other than saving 0 no matter the input)

Answer (score 3):

First of all:
 (If '`weight`' is a `UITextField`)

```
NSNumber *weightDouble = [numberFormatter numberFromString:weight.text];
```

With `numberFromString:@"weight.text"` you will be getting the value of the text 'weight.text' which is in fact 0.

But why not just `double weightDouble = weight.text.doubleValue`? (Except maybe localization concerns)